# How we can use mysql_affected_rows() in stored procedure

Tags: mysql

How we can use `mysql_affected_rows()`
 in stored procedure..

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use the [ROW_COUNT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count) information function.

> ROW_COUNT() returns the number of rows
>   changed, deleted, or inserted by the
>   last statement if it was an UPDATE,
>   DELETE, or INSERT. For other
>   statements, the value may not be
>   meaningful.
>
> The ROW_COUNT() value is the same as
>   the value from the
>   mysql_affected_rows() C API function
>   and the row count that the mysql
>   client displays following statement
>   execution.

Answer (score 12):

example

```
BEGIN
DECLARE countRow INT;
DECLARE roomTypeId INT;
        INSERT INTO room_type (room_type)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT paramRoomType) AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT room_type_id FROM room_type WHERE room_type = paramRoomType 
) LIMIT 1;
SET countRow =  ROW_COUNT();

IF(countRow >  0) THEN
    SET roomTypeId =  LAST_INSERT_ID();
    INSERT hotel_has_room_type (hotel_id,room_type_id) VALUES (paramHotelId,roomTypeId);
END IF;
END
```

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use `mysql_affected_rows()` in a stored procedure since it's a C API function. You can use `FOUND_ROWS()` function which gives a similar functionality. Refer this [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows) for more details.