# MySQL stored procedure return true or false

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have an update store procedure that updates certain fields in my table. I want the stored procedure to return true if the Update query is successful otherwise false if it fails to execute the query. I'm searching for different threads but I can't find the same type of problem. Below is my stored procedure.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`peter`@`%` PROCEDURE `do_update_bill_penalty`(
penalty_code_ varchar(255),
penalty_type_ varchar(255),
penalty_rate_ varchar(255),
charge_per_day_ varchar(255),
total_charge_ varchar(255),
total_net_due varchar(255),
user_ varchar(255),
client_ varchar(255),
accountnumber_ varchar(255),
job_date_ varchar(255)
)
BEGIN
UPDATE `bill` SET
            `bill_status` = 'OVD',
            `bill_status_description` = 'OVERDUE',
            `penalty_code` = penalty_code_,
            `penalty_type` = penalty_type_,
            `penalty_rate` = penalty_rate_,
            `charge_per_day` = charge_per_day_,
            `penalty_charge` = total_charge_,
            `total_amount_due` = total_net_amount_,
            `bill_modifiedby` = user_
            WHERE `bill_client` = client_
            AND  `bill_account_number` = accountnumber_
            AND `bill_reading_date` = job_date_;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to start with a better definition of "successful".

If you want to know if rows were updated then that makes your's a duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4458264/how-we-can-use-mysql-affected-rows-in-stored-procedure) (the integer value can be explifitly or implicitly cast to a boolean.

If you want to know if an exception occurred, then [add a handler](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-error-handling-in-stored-procedures/) (there are also lots of examples here on SO) to change the value of a flag

Comment: I hope you could help me with my stored procedure as I'm having trouble on understanding some of the syntax